# I'm a beginner and I have no idea why I can't catch NumberFormatException

Tags: java

In my simple program(below) that just checks if a number is odd or even, I think I have tested everything that the user(me) could possible do, and everything works unless the user inputs a string or double instead of an integer for numStr.  I attempted to `try{...}` and `catch{...}` but the catch isn't catching the exception that is thrown.

If for example I enter "s" instead of an integer an error shows up saying

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s"
```

Could you please help me?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HowToUseJOptionPane
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
     String numStr, result;
     int num, again = 1;

     do
     {
        try 
        {
           numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
           System.out.println("Requires an integer, try again");
           again = 0;
           numStr = null;
        }
        while (numStr != null)
        {
           num = Integer.parseInt(numStr); //gets number
           result = "That number is " + ((num % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result); //shows result
           //JOptionPane.YES_OPTION =0, no = 1, cancel = 2
           again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do another?");
           numStr = null;
        }
     } while (again == 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: widen the scope. catch ALL exceptions, then have your catch block spit out what kind of exception you caught. maybe that's NOT throwing numberformatexception after all... or throwing an exception to start with.

Comment: The exception comes from num = Integer.parseInt(numStr); //gets number. It's not in the catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the try block where you do the parsing:

```
    try 
    {
       num = Integer.parseInt(numStr); //gets number
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
    . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch the `NumberFormatException` because you are looking for it in a wrong place.

The first thing you do to debug a situation like that is to check which method would throw the exception of interest. In this case that would be the `Integer.parseInt`.

Once you identify the method, make sure the `try`/`catch` block includes the method call of interest. In your case, it does not, which means that your code would not catch the `NumberFormatException` exception.

Moving the entire `try`/`catch` into the `while` loop so that it encloses the call of `Integer.parseInt` method would fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to parse the number outside the try catch block. Place it inside the try catch block.

```
try 
{
    numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");
    num = Integer.parseInt(numStr); //gets number
}
```